# Video addEventListener of dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, html, video

Do you have any idea why I'm getting an error "Can't create event listener of null" from this:

```
    var my;
    my.newVidObj = document.createElement('video');
    my.newVidObj.src = "vid-source.webm";
    my.newVidObj.load();        
    my.newVidObj.addEventListener("play", function() {
        // Do something
    }, false);
```

Also, is there any way to use video tag methods on jquery objects (creating the video tag via jquery, for example)?

I edited the below answer to be correct, but it needs to be peer reviewed. Here is the solution:

```
var vid = $("<video />", {
    id: "my-HTML5-video",
    src: "video.webm"
}).bind("play", function(){
    alert('test');
}).appendTo("body")[0].play();
```

Comment: Edited my answer and +1 & star for figuring out most of the answer yourself ;)

Comment: @motionman95 one key takeaway is the use of [0] to make jQuery selections actionable by native javascript methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out these links:

http://www.chipwreck.de/blog/2010/03/01/html-5-video-dom-attributes-and-events/
http://www.dev.opera.com/articles/view/introduction-html5-video/
http://www.chipwreck.de/blog/2010/02/23/html-5-video-test-area/

I think it should be:

```
var vid = $("<video />", {
    id: "my-HTML5-video",
    src: "vid-source.webm",
});

vid.appendTo("body");

vid[0].play = function(){
    alert("yaaay!");
};
```

Correction by OP:

```
var vid = $("<video />", {
    id: "my-HTML5-video",
    src: "video.webm"
}).bind("play", function(){
    alert('test');
}).appendTo("body")[0].play();
```

Comment: It works for me but only if I use it with `play` event, it doesn't work with `ended` event...